# Connection error to search provider [Solr] : Unable to connect to [https://localhost:8983/solr], Core: [sitecore_analytics_index]

Tags: solr

Sitecore 8.1, never used Solr before, just switched from Lucene.

I downloaded the latest Solr and installed it using nssm. Generated self-signed certificate. Admin runs well at https://localhost:8983/solr/.

I created the core "sitecore_analytics_index" using the command

```
solr create -c sitecore_analytics_index
```

I can access it from the dashboard.
I renamed "managed-schema" to "schema.xml" but I get an error in the log informing me that the core was upgraded to managed and I don't need the file, so I deleted it.

When I try to access the Sitecore shell, I get the following error:

**Connection error to search provider [Solr] : Unable to connect to [https://localhost:8983/solr], Core: [sitecore_analytics_index]**

which is baffling as I can access that very instance just fine. Sitecore log is empty as it cannot start.

**Question**

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: If you open `https://localhost:8983/solr/#/~cores/` can you find the core above mentioned? Is its name **exactly** the expected?

Comment: what version of Solr did you installed?

Comment: as far I remember Sitecore 8.1 with Solr is tricky, you need to do some other changes...

Comment: Yes, I can find it and the name is exactly as expected. I'm running Solr 7.6.0.

Comment: Just check this compatibility table https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897 This may help

Comment: ...oh. Oh well, there you go - I'll just go ahead and download 4.10 I guess...

Comment: Gobinath, if you type that as an answer I'll accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use Solr 7.6.0 with Sitecore 8.1. This will not work, and ended up installing Solr 4.10.x.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue will resolve by enabling Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Analytics config file.
Enable all the config files related to solr and disable all the lucence config files in app_config/include folder